Using LlamaIndex, try to load HuggingFaceEmbedding on Google Cloud Platform and get an OutOfMemory error
I try to run LlamaIndex in a Notebook of the Google Cloud Platform. For that I am using the following
LlamaIndex (Version: 0.10.28)
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface (Version: 0.2.0)
runtime enviroment: g2-standard-96, GPU: NVIDIA_L4 x 8.
Here is the code:
!pip install -q llama-index
!pip install -q llama-index-llms-huggingface
!pip install -q llama-index-embeddings-huggingface
!pip install -q transformers
!pip install -q sentence-transformers
!pip install -q bitsandbytes
!pip install -q accelerate

import torch
import logging
import sys
import os
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig
from llama_index.core import PromptTemplate, PromptHelper
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding
from llama_index.core import (
    VectorStoreIndex,
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    Settings,
    StorageContext,
    load_index_from_storage)

model_name = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1"

Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name=model_name)

After running the code I get an OutOfMemoryError:
OutOfMemoryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bf164e32accb> in <cell line: 2>()
----> 1 Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name=model_name)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in convert(t)
   1148                 return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1149                             non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
-> 1150             return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
   1151 
   1152         return self._apply(convert)

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 224.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 15.77 GiB of which 11.88 MiB is free. Process 3802 has 15.76 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 15.46 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.46 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

According to the error message I set the enviroment variable PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF to 'expandable_segments:True' using the command:
os.environ['PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF'] = "expandable_segments:True"
but the error remains. I even tried different GPUs but the problem stays the same.
Has anyone an idea how I could solve the problem?
